# CRON string incompatability Quartz

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using Quartz to schedule jobs and display these in an UI. The UI uses an [NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser) to calculate the next trigger fire. However, the example string in that library is rejected by Quartz, and a string i have used with success to schedule a result returns invalid fire times from the NPM library.

Quartz Incompatible (works in cron-parser)

```
*/2 * * * *
```

CRON-PARSER Incompatible (works in Quartz)

```
0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *
```

Quartz throws Unexpected end of expression exceptions with CRON strings that are valid according to https://crontab.guru/

Can anyone explain why there is an incompatibility here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression,), there are different cron-expression implementations with Non-standard characters and different number of supported fields in the expression.

So, according to [quartz docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html), 6 to 7 fields are supported in Quartz, whereas in https://crontab.guru/ only 5 fields are supported.

And in cron-parser, 5 to 6 fields are supported.